# Stop a process started by setsid Debian 8

Tags: node.js, linux, debian, suspend, setsid

I ran a js script using

```
setsid forever sell.js
```

and I don't know how to stop the script.

I read similar articles but I just don't understand them as I'm fairly new to Linux.

Comment: When I do `ps` it gives me a list of processes (I think) and my script isn't there. `kill -9` it gives me usage for the `kill` command.

Comment: then `ps -auxwww` to get a list of all processes.

Comment: Thanks, if that was a solution i'd vote it ;)

Comment: @MarcB comment should be an answer...